# csv python разбить данные после запятой и скопировать данные вниз

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Есть файл csv

```
заголовок1;    заголовок2;     заголовок3;        заголовок4;
наименование1; наименование2;  544535425,4324324; 324;
наименование1; наименование2;  432432,4234;       324,4343;
наименование1; наименование2;  пустая строка;     3444,444;
```

как разбить строку 3 и 4 данные после заголовка и перенести данные после запятой вниз?
итог:

```
 заголовок1;    заголовок2;     заголовок3;    заголовок4;
 наименование1; наименование2;  544535425;     324;
 наименование1; наименование2;  4324324;       324;
 наименование1; наименование2;  432432;        324;
 наименование1; наименование2;  4234;          4343;
 наименование1; наименование2;  пустая строка; 3444;
 наименование1; наименование2;  пустая строка; 444;
```

подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd


with open('output.csv', 'w') as c:
    w = csv.DictWriter(c, ['заголовок1', 'заголовок2', 'заголовок3', 'заголовок4'])
    w.writeheader()
        

with open('example.csv') as a:
    for row in csv.DictReader(a):
        try:
            match = by_name[row['заголовок4']]
        except KeyError:
            continue
        
        
    row.update(match)
    w.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если csv файл отформатирован корректно,

**example.csv**

```
заголовок1;заголовок2;заголовок3;заголовок4
наименование1;наименование2;544535425,4324324;324
наименование1;наименование2;432432,4234;324,4343
наименование1;наименование2;пустая строка;3444,444
```

то будет работать следующий код

```
import csv

def pad(l, n, element):
    """fills list l with up to n elements"""
    return l + [element] * (n - len(l))

def explode_columns(row):
    rows = []
    column3 = row['заголовок3'].split(',')
    column4 = row['заголовок4'].split(',')
    column3 = pad(column3, len(column4), column3[-1])
    column4 = pad(column4, len(column3), column4[-1])
    for values in zip(column3, column4):
        row_c = row.copy()
        row_c['заголовок3'] = values[0]
        row_c['заголовок4'] = values[1]
        rows.append(row_c)

    return rows


with open('example.csv') as in_f, \
     open('output.csv', 'w') as out_f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(
        out_f, ['заголовок1', 'заголовок2', 'заголовок3', 'заголовок4'],
        delimiter=';'
    )
    w.writeheader()

    for row in csv.DictReader(in_f, delimiter=';'):
        res_rows = explode_columns(row)
        w.writerows(res_rows)
```

**output.csv**

```
заголовок1;заголовок2;заголовок3;заголовок4
наименование1;наименование2;544535425;324
наименование1;наименование2;4324324;324
наименование1;наименование2;432432;324
наименование1;наименование2;4234;4343
наименование1;наименование2;пустая строка;3444
наименование1;наименование2;пустая строка;444
```

Comment: на самом деле структура другая в ней колонок больше(https://prnt.sc/110wr6o), в некоторых есть и по 3 номера.
https://prnt.sc/110wrws сделал так, выходит ошибка(dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '', '\ufeff"ID"')

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("zagalovak.csv", sep=";").dropna(axis=1)
res = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    res =res.join(df[col].str.split(",").explode(), how="outer")
```

res:

```
      загаловок1     загаловок2     загаловок3 загаловок4
0  наименование1  наименование2      544535425        324
0  наименование1  наименование2        4324324        324
1  наименование1  наименование2         432432        324
1  наименование1  наименование2         432432       4343
1  наименование1  наименование2           4234        324
1  наименование1  наименование2           4234       4343
2  наименование1  наименование2  пустая строка       3444
2  наименование1  наименование2  пустая строка        444
```

Comment: "пустая строка;" не должна разбиваться, насколько я понял )

Comment: я исправил результат на основании исправленного Jack_oS вопроса. там уже отсутствует запятая в "пустая, строка".

Comment: так же explode и произведение множеств не должно происходить всегда . в случае нескольких  элементов в колонках подразумевается склеить их как по молнии при помощи zip и если один из листов в колонке меньше то просто деполнить его тем же значением